# creating custom popup background (dynamic height - resizable) made of three elements (top, middle, bottom)

Tags: css, background

I want to build CSS popup (or block) from three elements (top, middle, bottom).
I have always do it in simple way but there was no text area above the top/bottom part.
Now i have to build a custom background but don't have any idea how. Height of popup (block) should be dependent of content.
Is it possible to do without any JS hacks?

[image: popup background]

Comment: Upvote for nice clarifying image.

Comment: @Mateusz Did any answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found simple way to do it!

First create related block, inside content and three absolute blocks. Each of color don't overlaps other! Look at the example:

HTML:

```
<div class="popup-container">
    <div class="content">
        test 1<br />
         test 2<br />
         test 3<br />
         test 4<br />
         test 5<br />
         test 6<br />
    </div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.popup-container {
    position: relative;
}

.content {
    z-index: 9999;
}

.top {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.middle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    bottom: 40px;
    top: 20px; /* height of top */
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhnuh/5/

Answer (score 1):

Slice it into nested boxes etc.
What i've tried is to create a container first, the a `div` for the arrow, then the content (with your background gradient) and a wrapper for the content (with the red background) and the content inside.

**HTML**

```
<div class="popup">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="top">Content top</div>
            <div class="red-area">Your main content</div>
            <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Now you've a nice html basis, with which you can play with floating, padding, margin, background-colors and rounded corners, like this:

**CSS**

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
body { background: #eee; padding: 50px; }


/* .popup { width: 250px; } */ /* If you wanto to manually set a width for the whole popup */

.arrow {
    float: left;
    width: 25px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: white; /* your arrow image here */
    position: relative;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 25px;
    background: white;
    background: white url("your/gradient-image.jpg") repeat-x center bottom;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.wrapper {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #ff7f7f;
}
​
```

I've floated the arrow to the left, left margin for the content and paddings for the wrapper.

It depends on border-radius and box-shadow which are supported in newer browsers.
If you like to support older browsers, then i recommend you to use more images for the visual effects.

Hope this helps. **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5zdmT/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

-Divide the layout in 3 divs: top/bottom, with a fixed height and the top/bottom image as a background; and middle, using the middle image and repeating the background. Something like:

```
<!--Container-->
<div class="popup-container">

  <!--Top part-->
  <div class="top" style="height: 20px; background-image: url(top.jpg);"></div>

  <!--Now the middle div with the background repeating only vertically-->
  <div class="middle" style="height: auto; background-image: url(middle.jpg);
   background-repeat: repeat-y;"></div>

  <!--Bottom part-->
  <div class="bottom" style="height: 20px; background-image: url(bottom.jpg);"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) it's so easy to use and u can customize it's css to do whatever you want.

you also able to define the popup content as a content from another page like that:

```
$.colorbox({href:"simplepage.html"});
```

Now the popup width will fit to whatever your page have....

it's apowerful tool try it.